# Send an html email error content type or mime type

Tags: html, email, mime-types, content-type

I am having trouble getting this email to appear in gmail.

The code appears in plain text so i know there is nothing wrong with the mail server. However I need my users to confirm a link but i cannot get those html elements to appear. I have tried next to everything from mime settings to content type.

```
$to = $email; 
$from = "no-reply@alphaladys.com"; 
$subject = "Confirm Your Email"; 
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "
    <center> 
      <b>You are reiciving this email because you Signed up at Alphaladys.com</b> <br> 
      <font color=\"red\">Thank You, $name</font><br> 
      <b><a href=\"alphaladys.com/?71860c77c6745379b0d44304d66b6a13=emailVerify&key=$key\">Confirm Your Email</a></b><br>
    </center> 
    <br><br>© 2013 Copyright | AlphaLadys.Com |  All rights reserved.
"; 
$message .= "</body></html>";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject , $message , $headers );
```

Comment: what do you receive in  email  ?

Comment: the message came in raw, with the html code was displayed in plain text

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this example in my web host and it works perfectly :

```
<?php 

$from = "xxxxx@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Confirm Your Email"; 
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "
    <center> 
      <b>You are reiciving this email because you Signed up at Alphaladys.com</b> <br> 
      <font color=\"red\">Thank You, $name</font><br> 
      <b><a href=\"alphaladys.com/?71860c77c6745379b0d44304d66b6a13=emailVerify&key=$key\">Confirm Your Email</a></b><br>
    </center> 
    <br><br>© 2013 Copyright | AlphaLadys.Com |  All rights reserved.
"; 
$message .= "</body></html>";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
if(mail($from, $subject , $message , $headers )) echo 'Mail sent :)';
    else echo 'Mail not sent :(';}

?>
```

**Result :** [image: Result]